# QT with C++ in cygwin

Tags: qt, g++, cygwin

I am just trying to get started with QT and I am using C++ on cygwin(gcc-g++).
Can anyone please let me know the packages I need to install from the cygwin setup to have a proper working QT environment to make it work with C++ or point me to the information please?

Comment: I cannot help you with your specific problem, but I can recommend that you download Qt and Qt creator from [qt.io](https://www.qt.io). With this everything will work out-of-the-box.

Comment: AFAIK, cygwin implies Windows, so just do normal Windows Qt installation. When you are on Linux then you can try installing packages.

Comment: QT4 or QT5 ? Looks on libQt.. packages on https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html for a list of available packages. As minimum you need to install libQtCore4-devel or libQt5Core-devel

Answer (score 2):

If you want to develop Qt for Windows applications, you need to download and install Qt for Windows development packages from https://qt.io/ , as well as build tools (such as MinGW-w64 GCC) and SDKs for Windows, not Cygwin.

Compilers, other build tools and Cygwin SDKs in the Cygwin environment, are for Cygwin development, they can't be used with Qt for Windows.

You can still install Qt for Cygwin development packages from Cygwin repo, if you want. But remember the resulting Qt applications from this platform are Cygwin programs, and can't be used independently on Windows without Cygwin. And Qt GUI applications for Cygwin will requiring an X server to run, so it is probably not the thing that you expecting.

In most cases, please consider Cygwin and Windows are 2 separated platforms.